# Not able to autofit rowhight of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have to autofit hight of row after adjusting column width and wrapping text.

I have written below code:

```
Sub mycode()

Sheet1.Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 30
Sheet1.Columns("A:A").WrapText = True
Sheet1.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Code works fine when data of cell have less content.
 But when cell data is large, all data is not shown correctly.
cell misses some data.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Rows have a maximum height of 682 pixels. Is it hitting that limit?

Comment: Yes. it is hitting that limit.

Comment: OK. There is nothing you can do about that, except that you can make column A wider so that more text can be displayed in the visible area of cells.

Answer (score 0):

This question has appeared over on the SuperUser site ([here](https://superuser.com/questions/389976/how-to-make-excels-auto-fit-row-height-feature-actually-auto-fit-the-row-heig)) prior to your question.
My suggestion is to try the chosen answer from that post first. I hope it helps.

> User NickCarrington's [Answer](https://superuser.com/a/515038/551593):
>
> A method I just found (extending the previous post a little):
>
> - Select the whole sheet.
> - Resize a column a little wider (because the
>   whole sheet is selected, all the columns will get wider)
> - Double-click a row separator - the row height will be auto-fitted
> - Double-click a column separator - the column widths will be auto-fitted
>
> Voila!

Comment: Hi CaffeinatedCoder, Thanks for your feedback. But i want to keep columnwidth to 30 only. It is ok if row height is adjusted. Actually when i increase column width beyond 30, while printing it will show small size letters.